# Webpack build process - module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module *

Tags: build, webpack

I am receiving lots of errors when trying to build my application using Webpack and have no idea what to do. I have looked around at other solutions that suggest adding things like `target: 'web'` and `node: {fs: "empty"}` to the webpack.config.prod.js but none of these have cleared the errors. Below is a selection of errors (there are about 150 in total) in the console after running `sudo npm run build`:

> ERROR in ./~/ejs/lib/ejs.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve
>   module 'fs' in /tidee/auth_app/node_modules/ejs/lib  @
>   ./~/ejs/lib/ejs.js 47:9-22
>
> ERROR in ./~/express/lib/request.js Module not found: Error: Cannot
>   resolve module 'net' in /tidee/auth_app/node_modules/express/lib  @
>   ./~/express/lib/request.js 18:11-25
>
> ERROR in ./~/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js Module not found: Error:
>   Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../package in
>   /tidee/auth_app/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib  @
>   ./~/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 60:16-37
>
> ERROR in ./~/ps-tree/index.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve
>   module 'child_process' in /tidee/auth_app/node_modules/ps-tree  @
>   ./~/ps-tree/index.js 3:12-36

Below is my webpack.config.prod.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");
var CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const pkg = require("./package.json");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).filter(function (v) {
            return v;
        }),
        app: path.join(__dirname, '/client/src/app.jsx')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'http://example.com/public/'
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve('./client/dist'),
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.less', '.css'],
        alias: {
            'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            loaders: ['babel'],
            include: path.join(__dirname, '/shared')
        },{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loaders: ['react-hot','babel?' + JSON.stringify({
                presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
            })],
            include: path.join(__dirname, '/client/src')
        },{
            test: /\.less$/,
            loaders: ['style', 'css', 'less']
        },{
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: ['style', 'css']
        },
        {
            test: /\.ico$/,
            loader: "file-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.png$/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
        },
        {
            test: /\.jpg$/,
            loader: "file-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
        },
        {
            test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url'
        },
        {
            test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'file'
        },
        {
            test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
        },{
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: "json-loader"
        }]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            "$":"jquery",
            "jQuery":"jquery",
            'global.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'typeof window': '\"object\"' }),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(), //dedupe similar code
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            asset: "[path].gz[query]",
            algorithm: "gzip",
            test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
        })
    ]
};
```

**Note:** I am using Node v7.2.1 and Webpack v1.14.0